# How does GitLab run commands in the `node` container?

Tags: docker, gitlab

If I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like:

```yaml
image: node:latest

test:
  script:
    - npm install
```

This runs fine - but if I run `docker run --rm -it node:latest`, it drops me at a node shell, which doesn't recognise `npm`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it node:latest
Welcome to Node.js v21.6.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
> npm install
npm install
npm should be run outside of the Node.js REPL, in your normal shell.
(Press Ctrl+D to exit.)
>
```

I thought GitLab used whatever shell the container presented - is it secretly doing something like passing `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` to the docker command to get a shell it can run `npm`, etc. on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does GitLab run commands in the `node` container?

The image entrypoint is just set to start a node shell.

> is it secretly doing something like

Yes.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#where-scripts-are-executed

Comment: Ah, that helps - think the key point I was missing was that it runs it _and  then_ execs into it, it doesn't actually interact with the entrypoint shell - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `node` image is a little confusing in that it can interpret its command in two different ways.  If you run

```bash
docker run -v $PWD:/app -w /app node \
  index.js
```

then it runs the script, as though you had run `node index.js`.  But if you give it a normal command

```bash
docker run -v $PWD:/app -w /app --rm node \
  npm ls
```

it just runs it.  This behavior comes from [the image's entrypoint wrapper script](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a54ad036b53ed4d64744aa5aba25e78be5e4e7b1/20/bookworm/docker-entrypoint.sh): if the provided command isn't an executable shell command, then `node` is prepended to it.

This also explains the default behavior from `docker run -i node` you show above: if the command is empty, then it's not a shell command and `node` is prepended to it, so the effective main container command is just `node` and it launches the interactive REPL.

I think of the "standard" path to run a command in a container as to `docker run ... the-command` in a new container.  Especially if programs are invoking Docker, they don't start an interactive container and then run commands inside it (this is mechanically a little tricky and definitely harder than just creating a container).